# Android calculating values in dynamic Edittexts

Tags: android

I've dynamic Edittexts where I enter values(positive values bydefault) and when i press the togglebutton(out) on left of Edittext the value becomes negative. As soon as I enter the values on Editbox(I've called Textwatcher Listener in Edittext)the sum of all values are shown on below Tendered box. Please help me out with the logic, how do I perform this calculation.

Answer (score 3):

you can just check button is out,if out just visible the '-' icon if you used there and in tenderd just check the visiblity of that icon if visible then substract oterwise add.

just simple...use method isVisible().for icon..
and check on or off of the toggle button.